# Tensorflow: global_step not incremented; hence exponentialDecay not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to learn Tensorflow, and I wanted to use the Tensorflow's cifar10 tutorial framework and train it on top of mnist (combining two tutorials).

In cifar10.py's train method:

```
cifar10.train(total_loss, global_step):
  lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE,                        
                                  global_step,                                  
                                  100,                                          
                                  0.1,                   
                                  staircase=True)                               
  tf.scalar_summary('learning_rate', lr)                                       
  tf.scalar_summary('global_step', global_step)
```

The global_step is passed initialized and passed in and the global_step does increase 1 at a step and the learning rate decays properly the source code can be found at tensorflow's cifar10 tutorial.

However, when I tried to do the same for my revised mnist.py's train method code:

```
mnist.training(loss, batch_size, global_step):
  # Decay the learning rate exponentially based on the number of steps.         
  lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.1,                                          
                                  global_step,                                  
                                  100,                                             
                                  0.1,                                             
                                  staircase=True)                                  
  tf.scalar_summary('learning_rate1', lr)                                          
  tf.scalar_summary('global_step1', global_step)                                   

  # Create the gradient descent optimizer with the given learning rate.            
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)                                
  # Create a variable to track the global step.                                    
  global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)                
  # Use the optimizer to apply the gradients that minimize the loss                
  # (and also increment the global step counter) as a single training step.     
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)                  
  tf.scalar_summary('global_step2', global_step)                                
  tf.scalar_summary('learning_rate2', lr)      
  return train_op
```

The global step is initialized (in both cifar10 and my mnist file) as:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(): 
  global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
  ...
  # Build a Graph that trains the model with one batch of examples and           
  # updates the model parameters.                                                
  train_op = mnist10.training(loss, batch_size=100,                 
                              global_step=global_step)
```

Here, I record the scalar_summary of global step and learning rate twice:
learning_rate1 and learning_rate2 are both the same and constant at 0.1 (initial learning rate).
global_step1 is also constant at 0 across 2000 steps.
global_step2 is increasing linearly 1 per step.

The more detailed code structure can be found at:
https://bitbucket.org/jackywang529/tesorflow-sandbox/src

It's quite confusing to me why this might be the case (in the case of my global_step since I thought everything was set up symbolically, and so once the program starts running the global step should be incremented no matter where I write the summary) and I think this is why my learning rate is constant. Of course I might have made some simplistic mistake, and would be glad to get helped/explained.

[global_steps written before and after the minimize function is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ3WM.png)

Comment: The cifar10 tutorial is found at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py. I apologize that I could not add the link in due to my low rank on the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing an argument called `global_step` to `mnist.training`, AND also creating a variable called `global_step` in `mnist.training`. The one used for tracking the `exponential_decay` is the variable that is passed in, but the one that is actually incremented (by passing to `optimizer.minimize`) is the newly created variable. Simply remove the following statement from `mnist.training` and things should work :

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
```

Comment: I apologize for my lack of attention, but thank you very much!!! Got too bewildered by the framework.